# EADDRINUSE error when running React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying run a React Native project on a simulator (weirdly, it seems to run ok if I run on a connected (physical) device. When I run react-native run-ios, I get the following error:

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8081
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1286:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1334:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1421:7)
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tradesmartv4/node_modules/metro/src/index.js:193:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tradesmartv4/node_modules/metro/src/index.js:192:12)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tradesmartv4/node_modules/metro/src/index.js:50:30)
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tradesmartv4/node_modules/metro/src/index.js:61:15
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Server.WebSocketServer._onServerError (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tradesmartv4/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocketServer.js:82:50)
    at Server.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1313:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

I've tried all the fixes I can find (such as 'killall' etc), all to no avail. Appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Cheers!

I tried various KillAll suggestions, deleting npm folder, deleting ios build folder

Comment: It means something else is using that port already. Looks like you're on OS X? Since netstat is kinda crippled on OS X, try `lsof -nP -i4TCP:8081 | grep LISTEN` to see what's using that port. Pretty good chance it's another instance of your app, but hard to say.

Comment: Restart system is easiest way to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks. Tried both of these, but there is nothing running on the port, and restart didn't solve it.

Comment: Also tried changing the port - also doesn't work.

Comment: I have the same problem. Just can't start an existing project. `lsof -nP -i4TCP:8081` shows nothing. Tried to restart the laptop, still doesn't work.